# Try to use PhpWord on Laravel can someone helps?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpword

I am trying to use PhpWord for first time
so i write this code but it does not work i think the problem i do not how can i get the page data

all links are working good
I am confused about how to get schedule data like a query or something

my code :

```
public function getDecumentReport(Request $request)
{

    // get the Page Data
    $datas = Decument::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();

    // Get the Word Document
    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $document = $phpWord->loadTemplate('doc/dec_plan.docx');

    $management = Management::find($data->management);
    if($management != null) {
        $management = $management->name;
    } else {
        $management = "";
    }

    $department = Department::find($data->department);
    if($department != null) {
        $department = $department->name;
    } else {
        $department = "";
    }

    $document->setValue('management', ($management) );
    $document->setValue('department', ($department) );
    //---Use This Part Inside Foreach and Use a Word Table
    if ($datas) {
        foreach ($datas AS $data) {
            $document->setValue('name', ($datas->name));
            $document->setValue('describ', ($data->describ));
            $document->setValue('boll', ($data->boll));
            $document->setValue('type', ($data->place));
            $document->setValue('date', ($data->date));
            $document->setValue('unit', ($data->unit));
            $document->setValue('stitaiom', ($data->stitaiom));
        }
    }

    $name = 'Document' . time() . '.docx';
    $document->saveAs( "dec_plan/" . $name);
    $file = "dec_plan/{$name}";

    $headers = array(
        //'Content-Type: application/msword',
       'Content-Type: vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
   );

    $response = Response::download($file, $name, $headers);
    return $response;
}
```

the page is :
[that Schedule I want to export to word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYEiW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use XML in PHPWord:

```
class DecumentController extends Controller {
    public function DecumentPrintWord($id) {
        $datas = Decument::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();

        $phpWord    =   new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
        
        $sectionStyle = array(
            'orientation'       =>      'landscape',
            'marginTop'         =>      600,
            'marginRight'       =>      600,
            'marginBottom'      =>      600,
            'marginLeft'        =>      600,
            'text-align'        =>      'right'
        );

        $section = $phpWord->addSection($sectionStyle);

        $all_xml = "";
        if ($datas) {
            $all_xml .= "<w:tbl>
                <w:tblPr>
                    <w:tblStyle w:val='TableGrid'/>
                    <w:bidiVisual/>
                    <w:tblW w:w='0' w:type='auto'/>
                    <w:tblBorders>
                        <w:top w:val='none' w:sz='0' w:space='0' w:color='auto'/>
                        <w:left w:val='none' w:sz='0' w:space='0' w:color='auto'/>
                        <w:bottom w:val='none' w:sz='0' w:space='0' w:color='auto'/>
                        <w:right w:val='none' w:sz='0' w:space='0' w:color='auto'/>
                    </w:tblBorders>
                    <w:tblLook w:val='04A0' w:firstRow='1' w:lastRow='0' w:firstColumn='1' w:lastColumn='0' w:noHBand='0' w:noVBand='1'/>
                </w:tblPr>
                <w:tr w:rsidR='00292628' w:rsidTr='000C6BFD'>
                    <w:trPr>
                        <w:trHeight w:val='1000'/>
                    </w:trPr>";
            foreach($datas AS $data) {
                $all_xml .= "<w:tc>
                    <w:tcPr>
                        <w:tcW w:w='".$sign_cwidth."' w:type='dxa'/>
                        <w:vAlign w:val='center'/>
                    </w:tcPr>
                    <w:p w:rsidR='00001066' w:rsidRPr='00001066' w:rsidRDefault='005C41BA' w:rsidP='00001066'>
                        <w:pPr>
                            <w:bidi/>
                            <w:jc w:val='center'/>
                            <w:spacing w:before='60' w:after='60' w:line='180' w:lineRule='auto'/>
                        </w:pPr>
                        <w:r>
                            <w:rPr>
                                <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme='majorBidi' w:hAnsiTheme='majorBidi' w:cstheme='majorBidi' w:hint='cs'/>
                                <w:b/>
                                <w:bCs/>
                                <w:rtl/>
                            </w:rPr>
                            <w:t>".$data->place."</w:t>
                        </w:r>
                    </w:p>
                </w:tc>";
            }
            $all_xml .= "</w:tr></w:tbl>";
        }

        //---Load Items In Each Page End
        $section->addText($all_xml);

        $footer = $section->addFooter();
        $footer->addPreserveText('{NUMPAGES} '.trans('from').' {PAGE} '.trans('to').'', array('color' => 'black'), array('align' => 'center'));

        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        try {
            $objWriter->save(storage_path('MyPHPWord.docx'));
        } catch (Exception $e) {}
        return response()->download(storage_path('MyPHPWord.docx'));
    }
}
```

First Create a template of your word file and zip your word file and take xml of word file as follow:
[image: create a rar file of your template]

[image: select .docx file and click view]

[image: open the word folder]

[image: copy the xml file]

You can copy your xml file and arrange your code in following site:
https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer

Note: Remember just copy the table part of your xml file, the code that is inside "<w:tbl></w:tbl>" tags, do not copy the extra parts of your xml file.

Comment: Thanks for you, but I wrote the problem in get() it does not bring data i think should have some query statment or something . I will try your way but wish for another answer with out using XML.